# Pytorch slows down while training

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am training an Actor-Critic Reinforcement Learning algorithm like DDPG for many episodes. However, the time per step is increasing at first and then remaining on a stable level, like in the following picture.

[image]

I first thought I forgot to .detach()/.item() elements which I put in the replay buffer (a deque element of size 1e6) as it is listed in some other stackoverflow posts, but this is not the case. Has anybody encountered a similar situation before and can pinpoint me where to look for the cause?

Comment: Is your replay buffer filling up during the first 30,000 training steps?